# how to make pdns to sent notification to slaves not in "IN NS" record

Tags: bind, powerdns, cpanel

I have a cpanel box with powerdns as it's DNS server. it's IP address is 192.168.1.101
It act as a master, with 2 slaves (192.168.8.78 and 192.168.8.79) running pure BIND9

Here is it's configuration

```
[root@cpaneldev ~]# more /etc/pdns/pdns.conf
bind-ignore-broken-records=yes
setuid=named
setgid=named
launch=bind
bind-config=/etc/named.conf
bind-dnssec-db=/var/cpanel/pdns/dnssec.db
local-address-nonexist-fail=no
distributor-threads=1
disable-axfr=no
allow-axfr-ips=192.168.8.79,192.168.8.78
also-notify=192.168.8.79,192.168.8.78
webserver=yes
api=yes
webserver-address=127.0.0.1
webserver-allow-from=127.0.0.1,::1
webserver-password=_DELETED_
webserver-port=953
api-key=_DELETED_
upgrade-unknown-types=1
```

i have some domain hosted in it, created via it's CPANEL webUI
the generated bind zone definition:

```
zone "domain0.bino" {
type master;
file "/var/named/domain0.bino.db";
};
```

and this is a snip of cpanel generated BIND zond db file

```
; cPanel first:116.0.14 (update_time):1710237028 Cpanel::ZoneFile::VERSION:1.3 hostname:cpaneldev.binobox.net latest:116.0.14
; Zone file for domain0.bino
$TTL 14400
domain0.bino. 86400 IN SOA ns1.cpaneldev.binobox.net. emailserver.binobox.net. 2024031217 3600 1800 1209600 86400
domain0.bino. 86400 IN NS ns1.cpaneldev.binobox.net.
domain0.bino. 86400 IN NS ns2.cpaneldev.binobox.net.
```

Yes that 192.168.8.78 and 192.168.79 is not in it's "IN NS" record

Note that 192.168.8.78 and 192.168.8.79 is just a standard BIND9 server.

here is bind9 config of 192.168.8.79

```
root@risetdns02:~# more /etc/bind/named.conf.options

options {
          directory "/var/cache/bind";
          query-source address 192.168.8.79;
          notify-source 192.168.8.79;
          transfer-source 192.168.8.79;
          port 53;
          allow-new-zones yes;
          listen-on { 192.168.8.79; 127.0.0.1; };
          listen-on-v6 { none; };
          notify explicit;
          recursion no;
          allow-transfer { any; };
          allow-notify {192.168.1.101;};
};

zone "domain0.bino" {
type secondary;
file "/var/named/domain0.bino.db";
primaries {192.168.1.101;};
};
```

The initial zone transfer by 192.168.8.78 and 192.168.8.79 is work fine.

```
root@risetdns02:~# dig +short @192.168.8.79 domain0.bino soa
ns1.cpaneldev.binobox.net. emailserver.binobox.net. 2024031214 3600 1800 1209600 86400
```

I did some record editing
when I check soa at powerdns server, I got

```
[root@cpaneldev ~]# dig +short @192.168.1.101 domain0.bino soa
ns1.cpaneldev.binobox.net. emailserver.binobox.net. 2024031217 3600 1800 1209600 86400
```

But when I recheck 192.168.8.79, I still got the old SOA series.
I check log file of that server, and can't found indication that it receive any notification from powerdns (192.168.1.101)

I Also do 'journalctl -f' at powerdns box while editing record ... there is no indication that it send any notification.

I also do tcpdump on the cpanel-pdns box, and there is no traffic indication of notification sent.
If I restart bind9 service at the slave box, tcp dump reporting some trafic and there is indication of XFR.

Kindly please tell me how to check or do to tell this powerdns to notify all record changes to some server listed in "also-notify" event the server IP Address is not in "IN NS" record of that domain.

Sincerely
-bino-